# Generate a RFC2822 DateTime String - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, datetime

Hi I am trying to integrate with an api that requires me to pass a date in RFC2822 format that looks like this

```
Tue, 21 Aug 2012 17:29:18 -0000
```

I have been searching for hours for a node.js solution but I cant find any.

Comment: Using momentjs, you can do `const output = moment(date).utc().format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ");` (found [here](https://gist.github.com/AshKyd/8843581))

Comment: Does the offset have to be "-0000"? If not, you could do `new Date().toString().replace(' ',', ').replace(/GMT| \(.*$/g, '');`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Make sure to install npm package `dateformat`

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();

console.log(dateFormat(now, "ddd, dd mmm yyyy, hh:MM:ss l"));
```